# Contactless detection of current

Tags: electromagnetism, wiring

So I'm wondering if it's possible to detect a current passing through a specific cable inside a bunch, without being able to touch the cable at all... In other words : 
Is it possible to detect the current in a wire surrounded by others, without touching it or moving any of the others out of the way, in any way at all?

I know the exact location of each of the wires, as well as the current that may or may not be passing through them, if that's any help

Comment: The way this is currently worded, the short answer is no. Are the ends of the cable also off limits?

Comment: Yeah the ends are too. I don't know how to better explain it, but I can answer questions about it

Comment: Please give details regarding the overall problem so that we can actually come up with a working answer. Why can't we isolate that one cable? Why can't we touch it? And why is the current that may or may not be running through it interesting to you? Do you suspect the cable of being broken? What information exactly do you hope to gain from this?

Comment: The cables are behind a thin wall so cannot be accessed, which is why we can't touch it or isolate a single one, I'm looking to detect if there is a current going through it so a program I'm making to monitor the cables knows if one has a current running through it

Comment: Is there anything about the current flowing thru the particular cable that is remarkable i.e. makes it different from the currents that may be flowing in the other cables surrounding it?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Are there any known quantities at all? Positions of cables? Current flow that would exist if it was there? Type of current? You might be able to do something with a loop antenna if it's AC.

Comment: I know the current that would be passing through each cable if there is one, and I know the positions of each one

Comment: Okay, so there are known quantities. Is the current AC?

Comment: It's AC for sure. My original thought was using several magnets for some sort of electro triangulation thing, but I thought interference from other cables would undermine it

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question to include these details. If you know the exact positions of currents that may or may not exist in a wall an array of antennas that selectively couples some wires better than others may let you distinguish between the conductors, but I'm honestly over my head now.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but the answer to the "general" question, is **yes**.  It is possible to **sense** the current in a single wire inside (surrounded by) other wires. The only requirement is that the current being used, must pass through **only one** wire (at a time).
To clarify...
You place a current sensor around all wires. Run a current through one of the wires.  You should be able to sense the current with no problem.

On the other hand, if you mean detect (differentiate) one particular current when other "close by" wires are also carrying different currents, it may be extremely hard.

Comment: It's obvious that when OP asked "Is it possible..." he isn't asking for a yes or no, but for a **how**.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: An I provided the how (one wire at a time)!

Comment: +1 - I Disagree with this down voting. Even if the answer is not very good, it is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of a Hall Effect sensor can be used. HES is primarily used when we have access to the wire and we can form a loop around it physically. In your case, as physical looping is not possible you can use metal sheet of sufficient thickness and then complete the loop by making an imaginary loop(reflected part into the wall). I haven't used it anywhere, but I think it's conceptually sane.